# Vue.js: How to do validation in dynamic v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I get a JSON with 60 questions that are displayed every 10 out of 10. But I need to check that all of them have been answered before moving on to the next 10 questions.

My component:

```
<div class="test-questions comp" id="scrollb">
                        <div class="question" v-for="(q, index) in currentPageItems" :key="q.id">
                            <div class="statement">
                                {{q.id}}. {{q.text}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="options yes-no">
                                <div :class="{'active':relato.quest['q'+q.id] === 1}" class="caption option yes" @click="handleYes('q'+q.id, q.ck)">Sim</div>
                                <div :class="{'active':relato.quest['q'+q.id] === 0}" class="caption option no" @click="handleNo('q'+q.id, q.ck)">Não</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  
                </div>
                <div class="action-row">
                    <button v-if="pageNumber <= 4" class="btn btn-green" @click="next()"><span>Próximo</span></button>
                    <button v-if="pageNumber == 5" class="btn btn-green" @click="salvarRelato()"><span>Publicar</span></button>
                </div>
```

My Script:

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['grupoid','getperguntas','perguntas'],
        data(){
            return {
                perpage: 10,
                pageNumber: 0,
                relato: {
                    loading: false,
                    errors: '',
                    titulo: '',
                    sonho: '',
                    resumo: '0',
                    ck: {
                        c1: '',
                        c2: '',
                        c3: '',
                        c4: '',
                        c5: '',
                        c6: '',
                        c7: '',
                        exist: '',
                    },
                    quest: {
                        q1: '',q2: '',q3: '',q4: '',q5: '',q6: '',q7: '',q8: '',q9: '',q10: '',
                        q11: '',q12: '',q13: '',q14: '',q15: '',q16: '',q17: '',q18: '',q19: '',q20: '',
                        q21: '',q22: '',q23: '',q24: '',q25: '',q26: '',q27: '',q28: '',q29: '',q30: '',
                        q31: '',q32: '',q33: '',q34: '',q35: '',q36: '',q37: '',q38: '',q39: '',q40: '',
                        q41: '',q42: '',q43: '',q44: '',q45: '',q46: '',q47: '',q48: '',q49: '',q50: '',
                        q51: '',q52: '',q53: '',q54: '',q55: '',q56: '',q57: '',q58: '',q59: '',q60: '',
                    },
                    ckQuestAssociations: {
                        c1: [],
                        c2: [],
                        c3: [],
                        c4: [],
                        c5: [],
                        c6: [],
                        c7: [],
                        exist: [],
                    } ,
                },
            }
        },
        computed:{
        currentPageItems(){
          return this.perguntas['questions'].slice(this.pageNumber*this.perpage,this.pageNumber*this.perpage+this.perpage)
            }
        },
        methods: {
            next(){
                  this.pageNumber++;
                  document.getElementById("scrollb").scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});  
                
            },
            previous(){
                this.pageNumber--;
            },
            handleYes(quest, ck) {
               
                this.relato.quest[quest] = 1;
              
                ck.forEach(c => {
                  if (this.relato.ckQuestAssociations[c].indexOf(quest) === -1) {
                    this.relato.ckQuestAssociations[c].push(quest);
                    ++this.relato.ck[c];
                  }
                });
              },
            handleNo(quest, ck) {
                this.relato.quest[quest] = 0;
                console.log(this.relato.quest);
                console.log(this.relato.ck);
              
                ck.forEach(c => {
                  let index = this.relato.ckQuestAssociations[c].indexOf(quest);
                
                  if (index !== -1) {
                    this.relato.ckQuestAssociations[c].splice(index, 1);
                    --this.relato.ck[c];
                  }
                });
              }
        }
    }
</script>
```

What would be the suggestion to resolve this?

Comment: please share the script content

Comment: ready, I just edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `next` method check if every `qi` (`0<i=<60`) has value equals to `1` or `0` until the current page :

```
 next(){
   let valid=Object.values(this.relato.quest).slice(0,(pageNumber+1)*perpage).every(q=>q==0 || q==1)
  if(valid){
     this.pageNumber++;
      document.getElementById("scrollb").scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});  
   }

                
},
```

Comment: I just had to change this ``(q=>q==0 || q==1)`` , for this ``(q=>q===0 || q===1)``.  Thank you very much friend. It worked beautifully. :: :)))) (Y)